# Add Safemoon Swap as liquidity source

Tags: 0x

We want to integrate safemoon swap as liquidity source – can it be added for 0x API on BSC?

Factory contract: https://bscscan.com/address/0x86a859773cf6df9c8117f20b0b950ada84e7644d

Answer (score 0):

We now have a [google form for requesting liquidity integrations](https://forms.gle/3NeWnTtzFyxLyWhYA) for the 0x API.